# Stop Android connecting to external USB storage device

Tags: usb, external-sd

I have a car adapter with 2 USB ports, 1 of the devices is a continuos recording camera (with an SD card in it) and the other device is my Android phone (Sony Xperia, Android 4.3). However, when I connect both devices to the adapter the continuos recording camera stops recording and shows 'external storage' on the screen, and there is no way to stop this behavior on this device. In my Android device I can see no messages, but can indeed see the other device's SD card. There are no popups in Android when I connect to it. Is there any way to stop Android from detecting this other device?

Comment: Could you describe this "car adapter" further? It's pretty unusual for it to be set up with one device as the host and another as the peripheral.

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to connect together? Do you just want to power all the devices from your car, or do you need a data connection?

Comment: The car adapter is a standard el cheapo chinese adapter with 2 USB ports, like this: http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/KikAAMXQC-tS~bCl/$_35.JPG?set_id=8800005007  I didn't expect (and want) the 2 devices to interact, but for some reason they do.

Answer (score 2):

Use a needle or a pair of needle-nose pliers to break the data pins on your adapter, so they won't connect to the device. Breaking the data pins doesn't inhibit the adapter's ability to supply voltage across the power pins. Alternatively, it might be easier to cover them with a small piece of insulating tape; the easiest way to do it will depend on the shape of the adapter and what tools you have to hand.

Of the four pins inside a USB plug/socket, the middle two are the ones you want to cut off or cover. Be careful not to damage or cover the two outer pins. It should go without saying that you should do this while the adapter is **not** connected to anything.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought of this, but I would rather have a software based solution if possible. With Android being such an open system, I was hoping it should be possible to disable this functionality.

Comment: To be honest, it's a really bad idea to have the data pins wired that way on a power adapter. I don't like to think what it's doing to the power negotiation between the phone and the camera.

Comment: I'd also replace the charger...

Comment: I tried to put a piece of black electrical tape on the middle 2 pins, but then it doesn't work at all anymore. Maybe I'll have a look next time for a new charger...

Comment: I've invested 100 baht in a new charger, and the problem is gone. :)

Comment: If the problem is solved, then answer your own question and accept that answer. That way, other users won't keep posting suggestions you're not going to try.